# Is there a way within DataMapper to access paranoid deleted records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datamapper

I'm using the great ParanoidDateTime and ParanoidBoolean features of DataMapper in my rails project. All is going well but I would like to manipulate the "deleted" rows of models with:

```
property :deleted_at, ParanoidDateTime
```

set, using a DataMapper application.

I've tried Model.get!(id) but it returned:

```
DataMapper::ObjectNotFoundError: Could not find Model with key id
```

Is there a way to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `with_deleted` method:

```
stored_object = Model.with_deleted.get( id )
```

or in block form . . .

```
Model.with_deleted do 
  stored_object = Model.get( id )
end
```

Once you have loaded the data for the deleted object, manipulations should work as normal.